# The file `Runner.app/Frameworks/Runner.xcworkspace` doesn’t have the current file type for this location

Tags: xcode, flutter, app-store-connect

I'm building an app in Flutter, using the latest flutter version (2.0.3 stable). Everything works perfectly fine up until the point I try to validate the app prior to distributing it to the App Store. At that point I get the following error:

```
Invalid Swift Support. The file Runner.app/Frameworks/Runner.xcworkspace doesn’t have the current file type for this location. Ensure you’re using the correct file, rebuild your apposing the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it."
```

When I try to distribute the app directly to the app store (without first validating it) I get the same error but it also includes the text: `ERROR ITMS-90432`

I've spent a ton of time trying to resolve this, including having a very experienced programmer looking at it. I've naturally looked around on the internet and was unable to find any answers other than this one: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669948. Wether right or wrong, I do for some reason have the Runner.workspace file in the Frameworks folder. Per the suggestion in the linked post I therefore deleted the Runner.workspace file from that folder, but this does not resolve my issue.

Grateful for any advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You embed the `Runner.xcworkspace` to the final binary somehow. Open the main Target in Xcode and search for the `Runner.xcworkspace` file. Most probably, you accidentally added it to the `Embed Frameworks`, `Copy Bundle Resources` or any other Build phase that can copy files to the final binary.

[image]

Comment: You are spot on. It solved the error immediately. I've been struggling with this for over a week and losing a lot of sleep over it. I can't thank you enough!